# from where is image coming in overleaf template

Tags: graphics

I am learning to use overleaf
I started with a template EUSFLAT 2019  on overleaf. The template is available [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/eusflat-2019-template/jmqvcrhkqhgx)
They have given an image as figure1
some thing like this

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=60mm,height=40mm]{FuzzySets}
  \caption{\label{figure1}Example of figure title}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

In my browser I do not see any jpeg or png file which has this template in the template folder.
I see only following files

```
BIBeusflat2019.bib  eusflat2019.bst eusflat2019.cls EUSFLAT2019_template.tex
```

there is no images folder any where. What I want to do is upload the images from my computer to overleaf.
so I read the tutorial given [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/How_do_I_insert_an_image_into_my_document%3F)

what I did is I created a new folder called images. Now I have uploaded the image name 
proxy-architecture.png

so what I am not able to understand is how do I include this image in my paper.
What code should I put in  my understanding is

in following lines

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=60mm,height=40mm]{FuzzySets}
  \caption{\label{figure1}Example of figure title}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

there should some where we should be able to put folder name and image name. Where and how do I put that. That is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template includes `FuzzySets.pdf` which is taken as the image here. It is the only file with that basename but had there been multiple, say a `.png` and a `.eps` then you can always look in the log.

If you open the log file in the overleaf template that you link to then you will see latex log

```
</compile/FuzzySets.pdf>
```

as it includes the image.

Comment: thanks I downloaded the Fuzzysets.pdf I was not aware image can be embeeded from pdf also. I did open the log but what I get to see is following https://imgur.com/gallery/42F5qV5 so in this I think I am doing some mistake in opening the log file.

Comment: @koeradoera that error is unrelated, you have used the same `\label` twice.